# Stop timer JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timeout

I am trying to stop timer if div error div shows on page. Here is the code. I am not sure why clearTimeOut is not stopping timer.

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        function timeOutRedirect(){
            
                var delay = 60000; // time in milliseconds

                // Show message div
                document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
                // Display message
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<h1>Your order is being processed.</h1>";

                setTimeout(function(){
                        if( document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-NoticeGroup-checkout').length != 0 ){
                        // If error div is loaded
                        delay = clearTimeout(); //this is n0t clearing timer
                        document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
                        console.log('error notice div loaded');
                    } else {
                        window.location = "/processing-information/";
                }
            },delay);

        }

    </script>
```

```html
    <!-- Time out double order timer -->
    <div id="message" style="background: #a1f5b9; margin: 10px 0; padding: 10px; text-align: center; display: none; z-index: 99999;"></div>
```

Comment: setTimeout returns an integer which should be passed in clearTimeout

Comment: You could easily have googled for a description of how `clearTimeout` actually [works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout), which would have clearly shown you why your code doesn't work

Comment: Like Harmandeep said, you must pass an integer parameter (which identifies the specific timeout to cancel) to `clearTimeout`

Comment: Hi @Dave. Welcome to Stack Overflow. At Stack Overflow, people value questioners to do some research before asking their question. For example, if you do a Google search for "cancel timer javascript", you will find references to "clearInterval"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an interval, you can use the clearInterval() method.

```
const handle = setInterval(function(){...},delay);
...
// Cancel the interval
clearInterval(handle)
```

For a timer, you can use clearTimeout() method.

```
const handle = setTimeout(function(){...},delay);
...
// Cancel the timer
clearTimeout(handle)
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Comment: It isn't an interval, it is a timeout. Should `clearTimeout` be used? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout#syntax) says that they can be used interchangeably, though they recommend using the respective ones.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use for example:

countTime = SetInterval(() => console.log('Test'), 1000);
clearInterval(countTime);

this way you can manipulate variable countTime to stop when you call method clearInterval.